# Inserting missing portions of a sequence in python

Tags: python

I have two sequences, for example:

```
Seq 1: MAT--LA-B
seq 2: MATATLAB
```

Is it possible in python to compare the two sequences and then **insert the missing portion** in Sequence 1 without changing the rest of sequence 1, i.e, the final sequence 1 should be `MATAT--LA-B`?

The insert could be at more than one position..(I have a multiple sequence alignment in which parts of sequences are discarded...I want to re-insert these portions..)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You need to clarify more, I think. What you want to get for `seq1=MAT--LA-C` and `seq2=MATATLAB`?

Comment: Whatever sequence 2 has in excess of sequence 1, I want to insert that into Sequence 1. I do not want to change Sequence 2.

Comment: What does a - represent? Are your sequences strings or lists?  Without more information it sounds like you just want to refresh Seq1 to match Seq2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit less general than the preceding answer; but it looked like an interesting problem, so I figured I'd try it anyway:

```
import re

def find_start_of(needle, haystack):
    """
    @param needle    Search on first char of string
    @param haystack  Longer string to search in

    Look for first char of needle in haystack; return offset
    """

    if needle=='':
        return 0

    offs = haystack.find(needle[0])
    if offs==-1:
        return len(haystack)
    else:
        return offs

def find_end_of(lst, letterset):
    """
    @param lst       Chars to search for
    @param letterset String to search through

    lst contains some chars of letterset in order;
    Return offset in letterset of last char of lst
    """

    offs = 0
    for ch in lst:
        t = letterset.find(ch, offs)

        if t==-1:
            raise ValueError('letterset (%s) is not an ordered superset of lst (%s)' % (letterset, lst))
        else:
            offs = t+1

    return offs-1

def alignSeq(s1, s2):
    """
    @param s1 A string consisting of letters and hyphens
    @param s2 A string containing only letters

    The letters in s1 are an in-sequence subset of s2

    Returns s1 with the missing letters from s2 inserted
    in-sequence and greedily preceding hyphens.
    """

    # break s1 into letter-chunks and hyphen-chunks
    r = '([^-]*)([-]*)'        # string of letters followed by string of hyphens
    seq = re.findall(r, s1) # break string into list of tuples
    seq = seq[:-1]          # discard final empty pair
    # eg: "MAT--LA-B" becomes [('MAT', '--'), ('LA', '-'), ('B', '')]

    # find start of corresponding letter-chunks in s2
    offs = 0
    chunkstart = []
    for letters,hyphens in seq:
        offs += find_start_of(letters, s2[offs:])
        chunkstart.append(offs)
        offs += find_end_of(letters, s2[offs:]) + 1

    # get end+1 for each letter-chunk
    chunkend = chunkstart[1:] + [len(s2)]
    # get replacement letter-chunks
    chunks = [s2[st:en] for st,en in zip(chunkstart,chunkend)]

    # do replacement for each chunk
    outp = [c+s[1] for c,s in zip(chunks, seq)]

    return ''.join(outp)
```

Then

```
alignSeq('MAT--LA-B','MATATLAB')
```

returns

```
'MATAT--LA-B'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest beginning your search for a solution by obtaining [opcodes](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes) for transforming one sequence into the other. Opcodes can be generated with difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_opcodes. These will be tuples with instructions (insert, delete, or replace) and start/stop indices were the changes must occur to transform one sequence into another. A problem, though, will probably be that due to the vagaries of the SequenceMatcher algorithm, left-most matches always get precedence over potential matches to their right, which could yield an unwanted result in your case. You can always design your own opcodes handler function. I notice that in the example, the result could be obtained with normal opcodes by simply reversing both strings before using SequenceMatcher to produce opcodes, since the answer would require right-most matches to have precedence. Just a thought.

Comment: But opcodes only gives info about what the differences are...I would still have to manually insert the missing sequence isn't it?

Comment: I guess I could use the tags to retrieve the inserts and then append these successively in a for loop..